# Can't print index and sum of an array

Tags: c#

I have homework. I have to make a program which can input the length of an array with the value in it. After I click the "process" button, the program will make an output of index and value with the result sum and average from the array.

[image: codeArray]

I'm stuck and couldn't print the index and the value to the multiple textbox below process button.

I'm expecting the output will look like this:

[image: captureCode2]

Here's the code which I'd been successful write so far:

```
namespace ArrayProcess
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int sum = 0;
            string ind = "index";
            string message;
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(inputArray.Text);
            int[] varray = new int[count];
            for (int i=1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                varray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox(message="enter the value of array number "+i));
                sum += varray[i];
            }
            boxSum.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Array index is Zero based .. You should loop from 0 even if you display index +1 .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419343/how-to-sum-up-an-array-of-integers-in-c-sharp

Comment: And to add line to the multiline textbox = > [How to add a line to a multiline TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536958/how-to-add-a-line-to-a-multiline-textbox)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < varray.Length; i++) {...}`

Comment: The array variable should be in the Form1  not local to `process_Click` as many element in your form will like to have access to the input/array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for you  (boxAvg is for average)

```
namespace ArrayProcess
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int sum = 0;
            string ind = "index";
            string message;
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(inputArray.Text);
            int[] varray = new int[count];
            for (int i=1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                varray[i-1] = Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox(message="enter the value of array number "+i));
                sum += varray[i-1];
            }
            //Refer your list box here to add newly added values to the list
            boxSum.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
            boxAvg.Text = Convert.ToString(sum / count);  //calculate the average
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the array already has data :

```
private void Display()
{
    var columnHeader1 = "Index    Value\n";
    multilineTextBox1.Text = 
        columnHeader1 +
        string.Join("\n", vArray.Select((x,i)=> $"{i+1,5}    {x,5}"));


    boxSum.Text = vArray.Sum(); 
    boxAvg.Text = vArray.Average();


    var columnHeader2 = "Index    Value    Histogram\n";
    multilineTextBox2.Text = 
        columnHeader2 + 
        string.Join("\n", vArray.Select((x,i)=> $"{i+1,5}    {x,5}    {new String('*', x)}"));
}
```

- [String.Join(separator, string[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__), To join each row with a Carriage return/Line feed.
- [.Select((x,i)=> (...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__), To get each elment of the array an its index.
- [$""](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), For the easy string interpolation
- [{i+1,5}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding), To display the index `i` padded on 5 char.
- [new String('*', x)}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_), To create a string of N time the same char.

[Console demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MoRZfi)