# Adding all numbers in a given list

Tags: c#

I have just started C# but I can't figure out how you add all the values in a list.

For example, if you have:

`List<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 10 };`

How can I add every single value in this list, without manually putting it into a calculator?

Comment: Do you want to get total of all the numbers in the list?

Comment: `int result = 0; foreach(int item in values) result += item;` if you don't want any Linq at the moment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum up an array of integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419343/how-to-sum-up-an-array-of-integers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum):

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

var total = values.Sum();
```

Don't forget to include `using System.Linq` at the top of the file.

Or, if you don't want to use LINQ, write a loop.

```
var total = 0;

foreach (var value in values)
{
    total += value;
}

// total equals 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to linq, you must loop through the list and add it to a sum:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach(int nr in values)
{
  sum += nr;
}
```